# How do I convert multiple for loops with multiple conditions to Java 8 Stream Filter

Tags: java, for-loop, filter, java-8, java-stream

I am still getting used to using stream filters in Java. I am having a long time converting this conventional for loop into it since it has multiple lists and multiple conditions.

```
    CarTypes type = CarTypes();
    String carVariant = type.isASedan();
    String carType = "Default";
    List<Cars> cars = new ArrayList<Cars>();

    List<Cars> oldCars = cars.stream()
            .filter(record -> record.getCarYear().equals("2000"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    if (!oldCars.isEmpty()) {
        for (Cars oldCar : oldCars) {
            for (CarSpecs carspec : oldCars.getSpecs()){
                if (carspec.getCarName().equalsIgnoreCase("Toyota") 
                        && carSpec.getVariant().equalsIgnoreCase("Corolla")
                        || carSpec.getVariant().equalsIgnoreCase("Tacoma")) {
                    carVariant = carSpec.getVariant();
                    carType = Boolean.parseBoolean(type.isASedan()) ? "Corolla" : "Tacoma";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In this particular case, sticking with your existing for loop seems more suitable as it handles multiple lists and conditions more effectively. Additionally, you dont need to check for an empty list. Let the loop to proceed even if its empty

Comment: What exactly is your result? Are you only doing something with the last car?

Comment: Please don't provide just a snippet of your code.  Include the supporting classes, sample data, properly housed in data structures, etc.  In other words, provide a [mre].  This  will help us help you

Comment: And here -> `Boolean.parseBoolean(type.isASedan()) ? "Corolla" : "Tacoma";`  Why are you storing the boolean as a string and not as a boolean.  typically `is*` naming conventions imply that you are turning a `true` or `false` value.  Even if it is required to be a String, parse it in the method when it is called, not after the string has been returned.  And shouldn't `type` actually be `carVariant`? Otherwise, you are using the fixed value `type` from above.

Comment: Having provided the above comments, I have to ask if your program even works sans streams.  Some it isn't really clear to me.

Comment: Unlike @Melron I get the feeling that you may well use a stream operation here. Not being able to undertand the purpose and working of your existing code I don’t think we can help you, though.

Comment: The other comments already addressed some of the fundamental problems with your code, but there are more. Your condition `a && b || c` is obviously meant to be `a && (b || c)`. The `if(!oldCars.isEmpty())` test is obsolete, as the loop will already do nothing if the list is empty. Which is always the case, as you are processing the result of filtering the empty `ArrayList` you just created. Why is a car “old” when its `getCarYear()` returns the exact string `"2000"`?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

I typically just chain the *filter* calls.

```java
carVariant
    = cars.stream()
          .filter(record -> record.getCarYear().equals("2000"))
          .filter(x -> {
              CarSpecs carspec = x.getSpecs();
              return carspec.getCarName().equalsIgnoreCase("Toyota")
                  && carspec.getVariant().equalsIgnoreCase("Corolla")
                  || carspec.getVariant().equalsIgnoreCase("Tacoma");
          })
          .findFirst()
          .get()
          .getSpecs().getVariant();
carType = Boolean.parseBoolean(type.isASedan()) ? "Corolla" : "Tacoma";
```

After having another look at your code, it appears the *carVariant* may be what is used to determine, *carType*.

If that is the case, use the following code instead.

```java
carType
    = Boolean.parseBoolean(
        cars.stream()
            .filter(record -> record.getCarYear().equals("2000"))
            .filter(x -> {
                CarSpecs carspec = x.getSpecs();
                return carspec.getCarName().equalsIgnoreCase("Toyota")
                    && carspec.getVariant().equalsIgnoreCase("Corolla")
                    || carspec.getVariant().equalsIgnoreCase("Tacoma");
            })
            .findFirst()
            .get()
            .getSpecs().getVariant().isASedan())
    ? "Corolla" : "Tacoma";
```